# Why is recursion more efficient in OCaml than C++ or Java?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

This article [A C++/Java programmer's introduction to Objective Caml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/stephan.html) on the caml.inria.fr site says...

> As opposed to C++ and Java, recursion in O'Caml [sic] is just as efficient as iteration

For something like a factorial, it seems that a loop with a mutable variable would be more efficient than the stack operations involved with recursive calls.

Does OCaml really have a mechanism to make recursion more efficient than C++ and Java?

Comment: Some "good" recursive calls are compiled to mere jumps in OCaml and other functional languages, so it is equivalently efficient as loops. More technically "good" means at tail positions but it seems to me that the document intentionally skips this since it is just introductory purpose.

Comment: Appropriate use of “[sic]”, but “OCaml” is not written the way you had written it either. http://yquem.inria.fr/pipermail/caml-announce/2012-July/000000.html (“OCaml” was already the way it was supposed to be written in 2001 or so when I was writing my PhD, but it wasn't official then).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in certain circumstances. It's called tail call optimization. Take, for example, the following C-ish factorial function:

```
int factorial(int n) 
{
        if (n < = 1)
                return 1;
        else
                return n * factorial(n – 1);
}
```

This function goes n levels deep into the call stack before “unwinding” back up to get the result. The following is the OCaml equivalent:

```
let factorial n = if n <= 1 then 1 else n * factorial (n - 1)
```

Now actually, the above code will also go n levels deep into the call stack, just like the C-ish code above. Here's the C-ish function that accomplishes the same but with a loop:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
        int ret = 1;
        for (; n > 1; n--)
                ret *= n;
        return ret;
}
```

This function, of course, can be called any amount of times without overflowing the stack (even though you'll quickly overflow a 32-bit int). It's actually possible to write a synonymous function in OCaml. Now, OCaml's version will again use recursion. However, if we add an “accumulator” argument to the first function, it can be re-written as:

```
let factorial acc n = if n <= 1 then acc else factorial (acc * n) (n – 1)
```

The acc argument can be thought of as “accumulating” the result of all previous recursive calls to factorial. The key effect is that the expression “n * factorial (n -1)” above morphs into the expression “factorial (acc * n) (n – 1)” below. In the second expression, the recursive call to factorial is the top-level of the expression, meaning that no additional operations on it need to be performed to get the function's return value. This is not true of the first expression, where the top-level operation is the multiplication of the result of the factorial of n – 1 with n. When the recursive function call is the top-level expression, it is considered a “tail call”, and the compiler can and will optimize it into what is effectively a loop. Calling “factorial 2000000” on the first function will (probably) result in a stack overflow, but calling “factorial 1 2000000” on the second will not. Furthermore, you'll probably find the second OCaml function comparable performance-wise to the C equivalent (it might be a tad slower, but not by orders of magnitude or anything).

Incidentally, you might be asking yourself, “but isn't it unwieldy that the tail-recursive function has an unnecessary extra 'acc' argument that should always be 1 when being called initially by the user?” Yes, yes it is. This problem is easily worked around by nesting the tail recursive function into a “wrapper” function which calls it with the correct initial accumulation value, like so:

```
let factorial n =
    let loop acc n' = if n' <= 1 then acc else loop (acc * n') (n' – 1) in
    loop 1 n
```

Here, I've renamed the tail-recursive factorial function above to “loop” and nested it inside a function, which then calls it with the correct initial accumulator of 1.

It is often the case that these tail-recursive patterns can be replaced with the use of higher-order functions in the standard library, like List.fold for example, but not always.

Answer (score 0):

The functional programming structure of the language likely makes it easier for the compiler to identify and optimise recursion.

See: http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/if_statements_loops_and_recursion.html

`If you write your code recursively instead of iteratively then you necessarily run out of stack space on large inputs, right?`

`In fact, wrong. Compilers can perform a simple optimisation on certain types of recursive functions to turn them into while loops`

I suggest:

1. OCaml's compiler optimises tail-recursion into an iteration structure; AND POSSIBLY
2. All other recursion types are optimised with iteration and a stack object to simulate recursive calls (I didn't find any documentation to support this).

I know that at least .Net/C# is not likely to optimise across function boundaries. For example, in-lining of functions must be requested explicitly with an attribute, and even still may not. The JIT may inline and could potentially optimise recursion but doesn't appear to. This likely applies to Java.

I am not sure about C++, and would depend on the compiler you use.